# Header which contains list of all elements on page

Tags: header-footer, environments, strings

I want to define a ''question" environment which interacts with the header of my latex page.

The question environment will modify the header of the page which the command is found on. Ideally, the following code would generate the below page.

```
\begin{question}[1.5 (a)]
What is $a+b$}
\end{question}

\begin{sources}
Grothendieck
\end{sources}

\begin{answer}
$c$
\end{answer}

\begin{question}[1.6 (b)]
What is the value of the following determinant?
\end{question}

\begin{sources}
None
\end{sources}

\begin{answer}
$0$
\end{answer}
```

[image: What I want]

I already have the sources and answers environments defined, through the following code.

```
\newenvironment{answer}{\paragraph{\emph{Answer:}\\\noindent}}{\hfill$\square$ \bigskip \hrule \medskip}
\newenvironment{sources}{\paragraph{\emph{Sources and Collaborators:}}}{\vspace{0.2cm}}
```

**This is particularly challenging because we would need to get a list of all questions that appear on the page, and somehow append that to the \llhead. Hoping that someone who understands TeX string wizardry can help me out.**

Comment: Do you use clearly-defined page breaks via `\newpage` or `\clearpage`? Will there every be a question that flows over on to a subsequent page?

Comment: I can use either. For now, I have been using newpage. There may be questions that flow over to subsequent pages, but I can work around it if needed. @Werner

Comment: A similar requirement holds for dictionaries, where it's desired to know the first and last entries on a page, but there the presentation is "xxx - yyy".  (An exhaustive list would overwhelm the capacity of the heading area.)  That method might be suitable here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There will be no more than two exercises per page. Moreover, the exercises are numbered out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `fancyhdr` to place the desired information.  The exercises are a macro that is built up for each question, and erased one the page is shipped.  Since it uses `\global\edef` and `\gdef`, it might end up being simpler in LaTeX-3, but I don't know that well enough.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\exerciselist}{}

\fancyhead[L]{\exerciselist}
\fancyhead[R]{Your Name}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newenvironment{answer}{\paragraph{\emph{Answer:}\\\noindent}}{\hfill$\square$ \bigskip \hrule \medskip}
\newenvironment{sources}{\paragraph{\emph{Sources and Collaborators:}}}{\vspace{0.2cm}}
\newenvironment{question}[1][]{%
\global\edef\exerciselist{\exerciselist Exercise #1 }%
\noindent #1 Question\\%
}{}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\gdef\exerciselist{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[1.5 (a)]
What is $a+b$?
\end{question}

\begin{sources}
Grothendieck
\end{sources}

\begin{answer}
$c$
\end{answer}

%\newpage

\begin{question}[1.6 (b)]
What is the value of the following determinant?
\end{question}

\begin{sources}
None
\end{sources}

\begin{answer}
$0$
\end{answer}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]